# How to compare two strings in shell script with IF condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, if-statement

When I compare two strings using the IF condition in shellscript, I'm not getting the expected results.

This is the eventing log which something looklike in our application.
I assign this to executionstatus.

```
"composite_status": "deployed",
   "name": "Eventing-Function",
   "num_bootstrapping_nodes": 0,
   "num_deployed_nodes": 5,
   "deployment_status": true,
   "processing_status": true,
   "redeploy_required": false 

"composite_status": "deployed",
   "name": "Eventing-Function-on-expiry",
   "num_bootstrapping_nodes": 0,
   "num_deployed_nodes": 5,
   "deployment_status": true,
   "processing_status": true,
   "redeploy_required": false
 
"composite_status": "deployed",
   "name": "Eventing-Function-dev",
   "num_bootstrapping_nodes": 0,
   "num_deployed_nodes": 5,
   "deployment_status": true,
   "processing_status": true,
   "redeploy_required": false
```

With the above, we are further assigning the "deployed" to status and the name string as well to the name variable. We have set of 5 nodes running with for loop.

The requirement is I want to check the above three eventing function status are deployed, if not it should trigger a mail alert. So I'm checking with IF condition matching the string $status with $cbstatus, but I'm getting this. I think I'm missing something here. Please help to sort it out.

**Output**

```
+ '[' 'deployed deployed deployed ' == 'deployed deployed deployed' ']'
+ echo 'status is not deployed at ' $url
```

**Script:**

```
for url in "${uat_urls[@]}"
do
    executionstatus=$(curl -sX GET -u ${admin}:${password} 'http://'${url}':8009/api/v1/status')
    status=$(echo $executionstatus | grep -o '"composite_status": "[^"]*'| grep -o '[^"]*$' |tr '\n' ' ')
    name=$(echo $executionstatus | grep -o '"name": "[^"]*'| grep -o '[^"]*$')

    cbstatus=$(printf "deployed deployed deployed")
    echo $status
    echo $cbstatus
    if [ "${status}" != "${cbstatus}" ]; then
        echo "status is not deployed at " $url  >> status.txt
        # mail that the eventing function is not deployed
        echo "$(<status.txt )" | mailx -r "xyz.testcom" -s "FE CB AS eventing service status" $mail_me
        rm status.txt
    else
       echo "status is not deployed at " $url >> status.txt
    fi
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: There's an extra space at the end of the first string.

Comment: You're translating newline to space. Since `grep` puts a newline after each line of output, `$status` ends with a space.

Comment: So either remove trailing spaces from `$status` or add a space to the end of `$cbstatus`.

Comment: Remove trailing space: `if [ "${status% }" != "${cbstatus}" ]; then`